# How to remove or localize an exported/global symbol from shared object in Linux

Tags: object, shared, elf, symbols

I want to remove symbol for relocatable section from an elf shared object.

Or
I want to localize a global relocatable symbol from an elf shared object.

How to do it on Linux platform?

Comment: FYI...objcopy command is doing the needed for .o or .a file  but not working for .so files.

Answer (score 0):

> How to do it on Linux platform?

You can't (at least not easily).

Most UNIX systems do not allow modifying a shared library or an executable after they have been linked -- they are considered "final" product of the link.